# Collisionless Boltzmann Equation in Relativistic Cosmology derivation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, boltzmann-equation

"I have been studying Oliver Piattella's book, Lecture Notes in Cosmology, recently. In Chapter 3 of this book, the collisionless Boltzmann equation is derived in the FLRW metric. From equation 3.145 to equation 3.151, what I'm curious about is considering the distribution f as a function of $x^\mu$ and $p^i$, and later transforming it into a function of the magnitude of momentum $p$. (I already know that there is another choice $f$ is a function of time $t$ and energy $E$, since we consider the homogeneous and isotropic metric. I checked this approach make right result)

Start from
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{d \lambda}=P^\mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu} -\Gamma^i \,_{\nu \rho} P^\nu P^\rho \frac{\partial f}{\partial P^i}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is affine parameter and $P^\mu$ is a four-momentum.

Consider with FLRW metric, $f$ cannot depend on the position $x^i$,
\begin{equation}
P^0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} -\Gamma^i \,_{\nu \rho} P^\nu P^\rho \frac{\partial f}{\partial P^i}=0
\end{equation}
and assume the spatially flat case
\begin{equation}
g^{\mu \nu}=\text{diag}(-1,a^2(t),a^2(t),a^2(t))
\end{equation}
It becomes
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} -2H P^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial P^i}=0
\end{equation}
Meanwhile the fact:
\begin{equation}
 P^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial P^i}=P \frac{\partial f}{\partial P}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 P^2=\delta_{ij} P^i P^j
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} -2H P \frac{\partial f}{\partial P}=0
\end{equation}
I confirmed this step. And the book tells, since
\begin{equation}
 f=f(a^2P)=f(ap)
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} -H p \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0
\end{equation}
Here is a my question, how to convert from $P$ to $p$?

I think, $P$ and $p$ relation is
\begin{equation}
 aP=p
\end{equation}
so i tried with chain rule:
\begin{equation}
 2P \frac{\partial f}{\partial P}= 2P \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \cdot \frac{\partial p}{\partial P} =2 \frac{p}{a} \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \cdot a = 2 p \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \neq p \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}
\end{equation}
What did I get wrong? I would appreciate even a small hint. Thank you for reading, and I appreciate your assistance. Have a great day!